Listing multiple url files in an email script from a check box selection
I am trying to group multiple url files to be listed out in an email from one selection made from a checkbox on an online form. Currently the way the html is set up, you will make one selection and get the corresponding named file sent to you (e.g. file one, two or three), but I would like this to instead be that you select the grouping and then multiple files are listed out and sent (e.g. folder one, then you receive file one, two and three). Example is listed out below. I have next to zero skills with html so any easy to follow guidance would be much appreciated! Thanks!
Screenshot of example form with checkboxes
#set( $outputByInterestFunction = [
{
        "pattern": "(?i).*\b(One)\b.*",
        "name": "File One",
        "url": "file one url here"
    },
    {
        "pattern": "(?i).*\b(Two)\b.*",
        "name": "File Two",
        "url": "file two url here"
    },
    {
        "pattern": "(?i).*\b(Three)\b.*",
        "name": "File Three",
        "url": "file three url here"
    }
] )

#if( ! $lead.downloadMaterials.isEmpty() )
    <p>Please find the materials you requested below:</p>
    <ul>
        #foreach( $outputSet in $outputByInterestFunction )
            #if( $lead.downloadMaterials.matches( $outputSet.pattern ) )
                <li><a href="${outputSet.url}">${outputSet.name}</a></li>
            #end
        #end

